# Как из массива stdClass объектов сделать массив массивов

Tags: php, массивы, объекты, foreach

Есть массив

```
$source = [
  "error": null,
  "result": {
    "total": 500,
    "pages": [
      {
        "page": "foobar.com",
        "data": 
          [
            {
              "date": "2020-06-05",
              "count": 358
            },
            {
              "date": "2020-06-11",
              "count": 501
            }
          ]
    },
    {
      "page": "npmjs.com",
      "data": 
        [
          {
            "date": "2020-06-05",
            "count": 453
          },
          {
            "date": "2020-06-11",
            "count": 491
          }
        ]
    },
  },
  "post_action": null,
];
```

Из него нужно получить такой же массив, только **все stdClass объекты должны стать массивами.**
Функция, которую я написал работает только с одним уровнем объектов(если в них нет других объектов)

```
foreach($source['result']['pages'] as $el) {
    foreach($el as $key => $value) {
        if($key == 'data') {
            $this->arrayOfObjectsToArrayOfArrays($value);
        }
    }
}

public function arrayOfObjectsToArrayOfArrays(array &$arr) {
    $tmp = [];
    $objects = $arr;
    foreach ($objects as $key => $obj) {
        if(is_object($obj)) {
            $tmp[$key] = (array)$obj;
        }else{
            $tmp[$key] = is_null($obj) ? 'null' : $obj;
        }
    }
    $arr = $tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function convert($source) {
    return json_decode(json_encode($source), true);
}
```